# How can I run a packet capture on an unrooted phone that I can call through Java

Tags: java, android, permission-denied, packet-capture

How can I run a packet capture on an unrooted phone that I can call through Java. Specifically I want to be able to run the packet capture command using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command).

I set up termshark using termux but I am unable to access that through Java. I also have tcpdump on my emulator but when I try to run the tcpdump command I get a permission denied error. Are there any alternatives to do this?